# Lowercase part of a string with XPath regular expression

Tags: regex, xpath, replace, xslt-2.0

In a node, a string might contain one or more substrings delimited by single or double quotes. For example

```
<node>Some text "and Some" More</node>
```

What I have to do is lowercase the text that is not surrounded by quotes, so the result should look as:

```
some text "and Some" more
```

I've tried two things:

1. with `replace`: `replace('Some text "and Some" More', '"([^"]*)"', '*')` this will replace the text in double quotes with *. But how can I lowercase it? This doesn't produce the desired result: `replace('Some text "and Some" More', '"([^"]*)"', lower-case('$1'))`
2. with `tokenize`: `for $t in tokenize('Some text "and Some" More', '"') return $t`. Since my node will **not** start with ", I know the odd entries will be the substrings surrounded by quotes. But I don't know how to choose and lower-case only the odd entries. I tried with `position()` but it returns 1 on each iteration.

Thanks for looking into this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Martin, There is a single XPath solution that works even in the most generic case -- when threre is no guaranteed ordering or number of the quoted and unquoted fields. Другите решения бледнеят :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a single XPath 2.0 expression that processes in the desired way any mixture of quoted and unquoted strings -- in any order**:

```
  string-join(
  (for $str in tokenize(replace(., "(.*?)("".*?"")([^""]*)", "|$1|$2|$3|", "x"),"\|")
     return
      if(not(contains($str, """")))
        then lower-case($str)
        else $str
  ),
  "")
```

**For a comprehensive test, I evaluate the above expression on the following XML document:**

```
<node>Some "Text""and Some" More "Text" XXX "Even More"</node>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
some "Text""and Some" more "Text" xxx "Even More"
```

---

**XSLT 2.0 verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  'string-join(
  (for $str in tokenize(replace(., "(.*?)("".*?"")([^""]*)", "|$1|$2|$3|", "x"),"\|")
     return
      if(not(contains($str, """")))
        then lower-case($str)
        else $str
  ),
  "")
  '/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the XPath expression is evaluated, and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
some "Text""and Some" more "Text" xxx "Even More"
```

---

**Finally, an XSLT 2.0 solution -- much easier to write and understand:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex='".*?"'>
   <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:sequence select="lower-case(.)"/>
   </xsl:non-matching-substring>
   <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:sequence select="."/></xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XSLT solution is really beautiful. Thanks. One annoying detail: it adds an extra space around a matching substring. I wonder why.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov, Just replace the `xsl:sequence` instructions with `xsl:value-of`. I thought that you didn't want an XSLT splotion. It seems you don't mind. I'll tag your question as "xslt-2.0"

Comment: That works great. The XSLT solution is much cleaner and much nicer, so I prefer it. What on Earth is the difference between `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:sequence`?

Comment: @MartinDimitrov, When a sequence produced by `xsl:sequence` is serialized, a space is used as a delimiter between the items. On the other side, `xsl:value-of` produces (in this case) a single text node. All such consecutive text nodes are then concatenated into a single text node (as the XPath Data Model requires) and no delimiters are used in this concatenation process.

Answer (score 1):

Whew.

In case you'd like it the hard way:

`concat(translate(substring-before(//node/text(), '"'),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')  ,substring(substring-after(//node/text(), '"'), 1, string-length(substring-after(//node/text(), '"')) - string-length(substring-after(substring-after(//node/text(), '"'), '"')) -1) , translate(substring-after(substring-after(//node/text(), '"'), '"'), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))`

Just replace `//node/text()` with whatever XPath gets you to the text you want. 
I just did this for fun, this isn't the "cleanest" (HA!) solution.

You could make it faster by ensuring the node put in is the context node, or give a more direct path to it.

Comment: thanks. This looks a lot of fun :) Is it taking into account the possibility of having more than 1 substrings surrounded by quotes?

Comment: nope, just one substring. I'm not attempting more than that with just XPath.. thought it may be useful though.

Comment: BUT you didn't mention the possibility of multiple substrings in your question. "might contain **a** substring"

Answer (score 1):

**In XQuery** you can use

```
string-join(
  for $x at $i  in tokenize('Some text "and Some" More', '"') return
    if ($i mod 2 = 1) then lower-case($x)
    else $x
  , '"')
```

but xpath, only has a crippled for without at.

**In XPath 3** you can use  the ! simple map operator (which is kind of like a for, except it sets . and position()):

```
string-join(
  tokenize('Some text "and Some" More', '"') !
    if (position() mod 2 = 1) then lower-case(.)
    else .
  , '"')
```

And finally in **XPath 2** you can iterate over the index and get the substring for each index:

```
string-join(
  for $i in 1 to count(tokenize('Some text "and Some" More', '"')) return
    if ($i mod 2 = 1) then lower-case(tokenize('Some text "and Some" More', '"')[$i])
    else tokenize('Some text "and Some" More', '"')[$i]
  , '"')
```