# extract text between single quotes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Would need to extract the text after the **single quotes**.

E.g.:

```
<div>('show')</div>
```

The variables is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="showName" select="substring-before(substring-after(//x:div, '%28%27'), '%27%29')" />
```

The result is none, the [encoding caracters](http://www.vermontdatabase.com/cloudwriter/url_encoding.htm).

I think it can not be used **%28%27** and **%27%29**. This is correct?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0**:

**Just use**:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vshowName" select=
 'substring-before(substring-after(/*, "&apos;"), "&apos;")'/>
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vshowName" select=
 'substring-before(substring-after(/*, "&apos;"), "&apos;")'/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vshowName"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<div>('show')</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
show
```

---

**XSLT 2.0**:

**In XSLT 2.0 one can use either of the following two approaches:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPattern">
  ^[^']*'([^']*)'.*$
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vshowName1" select="replace(/*, $vPattern, '$1', 'x')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vshowName2" select=
 'replace(/*, "^[^&apos;]*&apos;([^&apos;]*)&apos;.*$", "$1", "x")'/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vshowName2"/>
===============
  <xsl:value-of select="$vshowName1"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the evaluation of both XPath expressions produces the same result**:

```
show
===============
show
```

**Do note**:

If you want *with a single Xpath expression* (making `xsl:analyze-string` unnecessary) to extract/process *all* substrings surrounded by quotes (where there is unlimited possible number of such substrings), see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402185/36305

**Finally, using [`xsl:analyze-string`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="'(.*?)'">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
     <xsl:sequence select="regex-group(1)"/>
   </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<div>('word1', 'word2', 'word3')</div>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
word1 word2 word3
```

**This code (from another answer) is wrong**:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="//div" regex="'(.*)'">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

**When applied on the above XML document it produces:**

```
(word1', 'word2', 'word3)
```

Comment: The XSLT solution is really beautiful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Techniques

If you are familiar with [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) you could also use [`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string).

#### Code Sample

Extract content between the single quotes. The content is later referred using `regex-group(1)` ) :

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="//x:div" regex="'(.*)'">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```