# extract text in file between nth occurence of special character

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to find out how to extract some information from a node in the XML where the information is between the 2nd and 3rd "|" in the answer...
because the length of the words contained can vary in length, so the only constant is the "|"

```
<root>
  <item>Apple|Pear|Orange|fig|Cherry|Banana</item>
</root>
```

I have already seen this example of a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593106/extract-text-between-single-quotes-in-xslt), but it doesn't quite answer the situation of finding the nth character, just between two known characters.

So I want to find "Orange" as my answer no matter what you change the other names to in the rest of the array.

Comment: if the data is really this simple, use `awk -F'|' '/^[<]item/{print $3}' data.xml` worst case, you may even need `/^[\<]item/...`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For a low value of *n* (such as 3 in your example), you could use:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(item, '|'), '|'), '|')"/>
   ```
2. For higher values of *n*, or values unknown in advance, you would
   have to call a named recursive template:

   ```
   <xsl:template name="get-Nth-value">
       <xsl:param name="list"/>
       <xsl:param name="N"/>
       <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$N = 1">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($list, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter) and $N > 1">
               <!-- recursive call -->
               <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
                   <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list, $delimiter)"/>
                   <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N - 1"/>
                   <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
               </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

   Example of call:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="item">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
               <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
               <xsl:with-param name="N" select="3"/>
           </xsl:call-template>    
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
3. If your processor supports it, you could use the EXSLT
   [`str:tokenize()`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) extension function:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(item, '|')[3]" />
   ```

Comment: Ok got around to finally implimenting this one, I was able to use the option 3 from @michael-hor257k, that was brilliant, just needed to add the following items in my namespace `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str"` then used your `<xsl:vlaue-of select="str:tokenize(item, '|')[3]" />`

Comment: Here is an interesting twist to the str:tokenize(), if you have an array that contains "|" as the separator and you have || as an answer, the Tokenize doesn't include that empty space or "null" answer. I have an array occasionally that can be `"apple|pear||lemon"` and another can be `"apple|pear|orange|lemon"` which means a call of `<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(item, '|')[3]" />` can produce lemon or orange. Anyone got suggestions about protecting against this? is there a way to make the tokenize include "null" entries?

Comment: @AlistairLindsay-Macfadyen You have been given alternatives.